# How to offer platform-specific implementations of a module?

Tags: python

I need to make one function in a module platform-independent by offering several implementations, without changing any files that import it. The following works:

`do_it = getattr(__import__(__name__), "do_on_" + sys.platform)`

...but breaks if the module is put into a package.

An alternative would be an if/elif with hard-coded calls to the others in do_it().

Anything better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `globals()['do_on_' + platform]` instead of the `getattr` call and your original idea should work whether this is inside a package or not.

Answer (score 5):

Put the code for platform support in different files in your package. Then add this to the file people are supposed to import from:

```
if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
    from ._windows_support import *
elif sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
    from ._unix_support import *
else:
    raise ImportError("my module doesn't support this system")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a platform specific instance of an class you should look into the Factory Pattern:
[link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

[Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/file_handling/index.html#d0e14344) offers the exceptions alternative.

Comment: Link is broken. Could you replace it?

Comment: Cannot suggest edit so here's a link https://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/file_handling/index.html#d0e14344