# Conditional definition of a function in a module

Tags: python, design-patterns, cross-platform

My question is about finding the "good way" of defining a function whose implementation differs according to a given criterion. This function will be called from several scripts, therefore I must place it in a module.

For the sake of example, my criterion concerns which platform the script is run on, but be clear that the test could bear upon anything. My functions allow persistent definition/retrieving of environment variables, so I created a module named persistenv.py according to the following scheme (SOLUTION 1) :

```
# CROSS-PLATFORM PART
def my_function1() :
    # ... body1 ...

# WINDOWS-ONLY PART
if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win') :
    def my_function2() :
        # ...body2 for Windows...

# LINUX-ONLY PART
elif sys.platform.lower().startswith('linux') :
    def my_function2() :
        # ...body2 for Linux...

else :
    raise ImportError('Your platform is not supported')
```

The above introduces two possible definitions of the same function in a single module. Anyway, it sounded pretty much cleaner to me than testing the platform each time the function was called (SOLUTION 2) :

```
# CROSS-PLATFORM PART
def my_function1() :
    # ... body1 ...


def my_function2() :

    # WINDOWS-ONLY PART
    if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win') :
        # ...body2 for Windows...

    # LINUX-ONLY PART
    elif sys.platform.lower().startswith('linux') :
        # ...body2 for Linux...
```

I found another [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791098/how-to-offer-platform-specific-implementations-of-a-module) in which each platform-specific part was extracted into its own module, and then imported conditionally in persistenv.py (SOLUTION 3) :

```
# CROSS-PLATFORM PART
def my_function1() :
    # ... body1 ...

# WINDOWS-ONLY PART
if sys.platform.lower().startswith('win') :
    from persistenv_win import my_function2

# LINUX-ONLY PART
elif sys.platform.lower().startswith('linux') :
    from persistenv_linux import my_function2

else :
    raise ImportError('Your platform is not supported')
```

Up to now, I reached the following conclusions (and got the following questions) :

- SOLUTION 2 should hardly be used, particularly if you have several platform-specific functions my_function2, my_function3, my_function4... (as you would have to repeat the test in each of them)
- SOLUTION 1 appears quite simple (no extra files, a single test), but I wonder **how does Python behave (internally) if one needs to call "from persistenv import my_function2"** ?
- SOLUTION 3 seems more Pythonic (used in built-in implementations, os.path for instance), but **can't it be problematic when persistenv.py, persistenv_win.py and persistenv_linux.py are part of a same package (among other modules) which I would globally import by doing "import my_package" in the main script** ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a look at the Python standard lib, you see that all three of them are used:

- `subprocess` uses solutions 1 and 2; there are several places where the test happens.
- `os` uses a variant of solution 3 (`import ... as path`).

So use the one which seems the most appropriate and the simplest.

> [Solution 1]
>
> how does Python behave (internally) if one needs to call "`from persistenv import my_function2`"?

It behaves exactly as wanted. The function which has been defined when importing the module is exported.

Technically, the module is imported just like with `import module`, and then the given name is looked up in its namespace and put into the current one.

> [Solution 3]
>
> can't it be problematic when persistenv.py, persistenv_win.py and persistenv_linux.py are part of a same package (among other modules) which I would globally import by doing "import my_package" in the main script ?

Why should it be problematic? You import `my_package` into the main script, and then the main script (or one module of the package) does the said import from a platform-dependent module. That is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. I take it that this is no "dirty practice" to use any of the 3 patterns, it just depends on the situation. However, I do not fully understand your last point : I must be wrong, but when you `import my_package`, you load persistenv.py (which loads either persistenv_win.py or persistenv_linux.py) AND persistenv_win.py AND persistenv_linux.py, not necessarily in this order for that matter. Is each of these 3 modules binded to its own namespace ? (e.g. `my_package.persistenv_win.my_function2()` ?

Comment: @gromk13 Even if they would be loaded simultaneously (which isn't true), they would indeed have their own namespace. But loading occurs only on demand, i. e., only those modules which are explicitly loaded are in fact loaded.

Comment: My mistake, I wrongly assumed that importing a package automatically imported all of its modules. Actually, the problematic situation I described above would rather be the result of `from my_package import *`, with `__all__ = [..., 'persistenv', 'persistenv_win', 'persistenv_linux', ...]`, which would be quite a silly move...

Comment: @gromk13 Again: no. If you do this, you'll get your modules as separate namespaces. Just try it out...

Comment: OK, I've checked it out. Thanks for your precisions, I seriously need to get familiar with the import system !